# What's the R statement responding to SQL's 'in' statement?

Tags: sql, r

*a case*

```
df=data.frame(id=c(101,102,102,103,104,104,104),
         calmonth=c('01','01','01','01','01','01','02'),
         product=c('apple','apple','htc','htc','apple','htc','nokia'),
         bb=sample(1:20,7))

> df
   id calmonth product bb
1 101       01   apple  4
2 102       01   apple  9
3 102       01     htc  8
4 103       01     htc  5
5 104       01   apple 16
6 104       01     htc 19
7 104       02   nokia 20
```

**sql statement: get the intersection where id uses both product "apple" and product "htc" when calmonth="01"**

```
select id from df where calmonth='01' and product="apple"  and id in 
(select id from df where product="htc" and calmonth="01")
```

*the predictive result*

```
   id calmonth     product
1 102       01 apple & htc
2 104       01 apple & htc
```

**So what's the responding R statement?**

Comment: `df[df[,2] == '01' & df[,3] == 'apple' & df[,1] %in% (df[,2] == 'htc' & df[,2] == '01'],1]` # ?

Comment: you mean `df[df[,2]=='01' & df[,3]=='apple' & df[,1] %in% (df[,2]=='01' & df[,3]=='htc'),1]` *but the result is a little strange* `0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Comment: You might like to use `aggregate` like so `df2 <- aggregate( product ~ id + calmonth , data = df , FUN = paste , collapse = " & ")`, then subset on the rows that contain both `"apple"` and `"htc"` in the new `product` column like so `df2[ grepl( "apple & htc" , df2$product) , ]`. One way of quite a few (there are much better ways too).

Comment: `@SimonO101` Thanks! almost all of my problems were solved, but there is still another one problem as shown in my reply to `zx8754`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer SQL syntax then use `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("
      select * 
      from (
            select id,
                   calmonth,
                   group_concat(product, ' & ') product
            from df
            group by id, calmonth
           ) 
      where product='apple & htc' and
            calmonth='01'
      ")
```

Comment: Another question:if one id has the same product more than one time,assume that there is another row `id='101',calmonth='01',product='apple',bb=5`,then the resulting data will contain a row `101  01  apple&apple`,so how to change `apple&apple` to `apple`?

Comment: @jasmine_007 Please avoid asking new questions on comments. I would exclude column `bb` and deduplicate rows before running above script.

Comment: `@zx8754` So what i need to do if i have other new questions based on your answer?

Comment: Ask a new question and link it to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement doesn't produce quite the result you show. It returns (selects) the IDs only not that table and the merged column? No?

```
SELECT id 
FROM   df 
WHERE  calmonth = '01' 
       AND product = "apple" 
       AND id IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM   df 
                  WHERE  product = "htc" 
                         AND calmonth = "01")
```

in R that is roughly:

```
with(df, 
intersect(
id[calmonth=='01' & product=='apple'], 
id[product=="htc" & calmonth=="01"]))

[1] 102 104
```

Comment: A bit less keystrokes: `with(df[ df$calmonth=='01', ], intersect(id[product=='apple'], id[product=='htc' ]))`

Comment: @zx8754 True that's the essential operation, I just transliterate the original as requested though.

Comment: `@Stephen Henderson` No,it just returns the ids. Thanks for your answer and sorry for my unclear expression, I mean that my predictive result is produced by R language. If in SQL,my totally clear statement will be       **select id,calmonth,concat('apple',concat('&','htc')) as product from df where calmonth='01' and product='apple'
      and id in(
                select id from df where calmonth='01' and product='htc')**