# Aggregate error 'invalid type (closure) for variable 'paste'

Tags: r, aggregate

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966480/whats-the-r-statement-responding-to-sqls-in-statement) @SimonO101 suggested `aggregate` solution in comments, as below:

```
#dataframe
df <- data.frame(id=c(101,102,102,103,104,104,104),
                 calmonth=c('01','01','01','01','01','01','02'),
                 product=c('apple','apple','htc','htc','apple','htc','nokia'),
                 bb=sample(1:20,7))

#aggregate - SimonO101's solution:
aggregate(product~id+calmonth, data=df, FUN=paste, collapse=" & ")

#Error
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~product + paste, data = list(id = c(101,  : 
>   invalid type (closure) for variable 'paste'

Can't figure out the cause of this error?

**Version:**

```
Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, 64bit OS, "R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)", RStudio
```

**Update:** Opened new RStudio session, no error, still would like to find out the cause.

**Update:** dput:

```
dput(df123)
structure(list(id = c(101, 102, 102, 103, 104, 104, 104), calmonth = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("01", "02"), class = "factor"), 
    product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("apple", 
    "htc", "nokia"), class = "factor"), bb = c(19L, 17L, 5L, 
    15L, 16L, 4L, 9L)), .Names = c("id", "calmonth", "product", 
"bb"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Update:** conflicts

```
conflicts()
 [1] "dbCallProc"        "dbClearResult"     "dbColumnInfo"      "dbCommit"         
 [5] "dbConnect"         "dbDataType"        "dbDisconnect"      "dbExistsTable"    
 [9] "dbGetException"    "dbGetInfo"         "dbGetQuery"        "dbGetRowCount"    
[13] "dbGetRowsAffected" "dbGetStatement"    "dbHasCompleted"    "dbListConnections"
[17] "dbListFields"      "dbListResults"     "dbListTables"      "dbReadTable"      
[21] "dbRemoveTable"     "dbRollback"        "dbSendQuery"       "dbUnloadDriver"   
[25] "dbWriteTable"      "fetch"             "isSQLKeyword"      "make.db.names"    
[29] "SQLKeywords"       "summary"           "fillin"            "recode"           
[33] "untangle.specials" "%nin%"             "codebook"          "coerce"           
[37] "initialize"        "recode"            "rename"            "show"             
[41] "summary"           "dotplot"           "contr.sum"         "contr.treatment"  
[45] "contrasts"         "contrasts<-"       "Arith"             "coerce"           
[49] "Compare"           "initialize"        "Math"              "Math2"            
[53] "show"              "Summary"           "%in%"              "as.array"         
[57] "as.factor"         "as.ordered"        "as.vector"         "body<-"           
[61] "format"            "format.pval"       "kronecker"         "labels"           
[65] "print"             "round.POSIXt"      "row.names"         "sample"           
[69] "subset"            "summary"           "trunc.POSIXt"      "unique"           
[73] "units"             "within"
```

Comment: I do not get an error on MacOS.

Comment: no error here either. `stats:::aggregate.formula(product~id+calmonth, data=df, FUN=paste, collapse=" & ")`?

Comment: Is your dataframe definitely called `df`. `df` also happens to be the name of a function (density of the f-distribution). Otherwise have you overwritten the `data.frame` function. Try adding in `dput( df )` in the R session from which you get the error.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Yes, you are right, `dput(df)` gives some function. I renamed the dataframe to `df123` and `dput(df123)` added to the question. Getting the same error with `df123`.

Comment: Ok, and does `data.frame` or `paste` appear when you run `conflicts()`?

Comment: No, `conflicts()` output added to the question.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, final suggestion, if you make the data specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, i.e.  `df <- data.frame(id=c(101,102 , ... ) ... , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )` do you still get the same error (I notice you have some conflicts in `contrasts` and `contr.treatment` which *may* have a bearing.

Comment: Yes, I have tried removing factors, same error...

Comment: @zx8754 ok I suggest open a new session and repeatedly try the code, loading each package you currently have loaded `names( sessionInfo()$loadedOnly )` and see at which point you hit the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me...

```
> df <- data.frame(id=c(101,102,102,103,104,104,104),
+                  calmonth=c('01','01','01','01','01','01','02'),
+                  product=c('apple','apple','htc','htc','apple','htc','nokia'),
+                  bb=sample(1:20,7))
> 
> #aggregate - SimonO101's solution:
> aggregate(product~id+calmonth, data=df, FUN=paste, collapse=" & ")
   id calmonth     product
1 101       01       apple
2 102       01 apple & htc
3 103       01         htc
4 104       01 apple & htc
5 104       02       nokia
>
```

Try `conflicts()` to see if you are masking something ...

Comment: Tried `remove(list = conflicts(detail = TRUE)$.GlobalEnv)`, still same error.

Comment: This is not a solution, but it certainly put me in the right direction with reference to `conflicts()` function. Big thank you to @SimonO'Hanlon, too.

Comment: Worked for me too in a completely different situation. In my case I defined a variable `t` `as.vector` earlier and used it in a model, ignorant about R's use of `t` as transpose function.