# R function(): how to pass parameters which contain characters and regular expression

Tags: regex, r

my data as follows:

`>df2`

```
  id   calmonth        product
1 101       01           apple
2 102       01 apple&nokia&htc
3 103       01             htc
4 104       01       apple&htc
5 104       02           nokia
```

Now i wanna calculate the number of `ids` whose `products` contain `both 'apple' and 'htc'`  when `calmonth='01'`. Because what i need is not only 'apple' and 'htc', also i need 'apple' and 'nokia',etc.
So i want to realize this by a function like this:

```
xandy=function(a,b) data.frame(product=paste(a,b,sep='&'),
                               csum=length(grep('a.*b',x=df2$product))
                              )
```

also, i make a parameters list like this:

```
para=c('apple','htc','nokia')
```

**but the problem is here. When i pass parameters like**

```
xandy(para[1],para[2])
```

the results is as follows:

```
  product    csum
1 apple&htc    0
```

What my expecting result should be

```
  product    csum   calmonth
1 apple&htc    2     01
2 apple&htc    0     02
```

**So where is wrong about the parameters passing?
and, how can i add the `calmonth` in to the function() `xandy` correctly?**
FYI.This question stems from my another question before 
[What's the R statement responding to SQL's 'in' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966480/whats-the-r-statement-responding-to-sqls-in-statement)

---

EDIT AFTER COMMENT

My predictive result will be:

```
product    csum   calmonth
 1 apple&htc    2     01
 2 apple&htc    0     02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May answer is another way how to tackle your problem.

```
library(stringr)
```

The function `contains` will split up the elements of a string vector according to the `split` character and evaluate if all target words are contained.

```
contains <- function(x, target, split="&") {
  l <- str_split(x, split)
  sapply(l, function(x, y) all(y %in% x), y=target)  
}

contains(d$product, c("apple", "htc")) 
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The rest is just subsetting and summarizing

```
get_data <- function(a, b) {
  e <- subset(d, contains(product, c(a, b)))
  e$product2 <- paste(a, b, sep="&")
  ddply(e, .(calmonth, product2), summarise, csum=length(id))
}
```

Using the data below, order does not play a role now anymore (see comment below).

```
get_data("apple", "htc")

  calmonth  product2 csum
1        1 apple&htc    1
2        2 apple&htc    2

get_data("htc", "apple")

  calmonth  product2 csum
1        1 htc&apple    1
2        2 htc&apple    2
```

I know this is not a direct answer to your question but I find this approach quite clean.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

The reason that you get `csum=0` is simply that you are searching for the wrong regex pattern, i.e. `a something in between b` not for `apple ... htc`. You need to construct the correct regex pattern,i.e. `paste0(a, ".*", b)`.

Here a complete solution. I would not call it beautiful code, but anyway (note that I change the data to show that it generalizes for months).

```
library(plyr)

df2 <- read.table(text="
  id   calmonth        product
 101       01           apple
 102       01 apple&nokia&htc
 103       01             htc
 104       02       apple&htc
 104       02       apple&htc",  header=T)

xandy <- function(a, b) {
  pattern <- paste0(a, ".*", b)
  d1 <- df2[grep(pattern, df2$product), ]
  d1$product <- paste0(a,"&", b)
  ddply(d1, .(calmonth), summarise, 
        csum=length(calmonth),
        product=unique(product))  
}
xandy("apple", "htc")

  calmonth csum   product
1        1    1 apple&htc
2        2    2 apple&htc
```

Comment: `@Mark Heckmann`Thanks! But why not try `df2[grep("apple.*htc",df2$product),]` to get the above result? Actually what i really want to do is to calculate the respective ids contain responding products.

Comment: Thanks again!But when i pass parameters `xandy('htc','nokia')`,it occurs error:`replacement has 1 row, data has 0 `,because there is no any return value. And,I wonder if `ddply()` cannot contain parameters,i found parameters cannot be past correctly.

Comment: Yes, because the approach you chose depends on order. You have to specify the request in reverse order, i.e. `xandy("nokia", "htc")` for  it to work. The regex pattern `"htc.*nokia"` will not find `apple&nokia&htc` as in the example. Hence it returns a dataframe of length zero  and the error occurs. The approach I described first does not have this shortcoming. Yet, I understand that  it needs some modification to suit your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I see, I mean if a id use just product 'htc' but no 'nokia' in month both '01' and '02',then the result will be two zero lines,isn't it? When this happens, it will occur errors.And, I posed a new question like this one,expecting your answer, thanks![link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041252/r-function-contain-plyr-ddply-parameters-in-ddply-cannot-be-past-correctly

Comment: I completed the approach I suggested first.