# R function contain plyr--ddply(): parameters in ddply() cannot be past correctly

Tags: regex, r, parameter-passing, plyr

my data as follows:

```
>df2
   id     calmonth       product
1 101       01           apple
2 102       01           apple&nokia&htc
3 103       01           htc
4 104       01           apple&htc
5 104       02           nokia

para=c('apple','htc','nokia')
```

I wanna get the number of ids who's product contain `apple&htc,apple&nokia`,etc.
I make a function as follows:

> ```
> xandy=function(a,b){
>         ddply(df2,.(calmonth),summarise,
>                               csum=length(grep(paste0('apple','.*','htc'),product)),
>                               coproduct=paste0('apple','&','htc')
>              )
>                    }
> ```

**This function give me a perfect result as follows:**

```
> xandy(para[1],para[3])
  calmonth csum   coproduct
1       01    2   apple&htc
2       02    0   apple&htc
```

But What i need are not only `apple&htc`,but`apple&nokia`etc,so I alter `apple and htc`themselves to parameters,new likely function like this:

> ```
> xandy=function(a,b){
>         ddply(df2,.(calmonth),summarise,
>                               csum=length(grep(paste0(a,'.*',b),product)),
>                               coproduct=paste0(a,'&',b)
>              )
>                    }
> ```

See the differences? **I have altered 'apple' ,'htc' to a,b(parameters)**
But it is not at all what I want.

```
> xandy(para[1],para[3])
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default In addition: Warning message:
>   In grep(paste0(a, ".*", b), product) :
>     argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: just an aside: I'm not sure if this is the way you got the data but this concatenation of apple&htc etc in a single product column is a bad idea. far better to just create another row with the same ID then all these aggregations and operations are much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of MengChen and others, I get a straightforward answer.

```
xandy=function(a,b){
myStr_match=paste0(a,'.*',b)
myStr_match1=paste0(b,'.*',a)
ajoinb_match=paste0(a,'&',b)
ddply(df2,.(calmonth),function(data,myStr,myStr1,ajoinb){
summarise(data,
          csum=max(length(grep(myStr,product)),length(grep(myStr1,product))),
          coproduct=ajoinb)
  },myStr=myStr_match,myStr1=myStr_match1,ajoinb=ajoinb_match)
}
```

Maybe this is not the best answer, but it does work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution to your problem might be:

```
ddply(df2, .(calmonth), summarise, 
               apple = as.numeric(length(product == "apple")),
               apple.nokia.htc = as.numeric(length(product == "apple&nokia&htc")),
               htc = as.numeric(length(product == "htc")),
               apple.htc = as.numeric(length(product == "apple&htc"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your straightforward solution.But for more extended application,it seems that Parametric Methods are more suitable.